# Annotating an existing ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I ran into problems with annotating to an existing ggplot2 using the

```
plotname + annotate()
```

syntax

I was trying to annotate to an existing ggplot using a loop which aims to add text and arrows to a plot. While troubleshooting I discovered that the problem was far more basic than the loop (which is fine) or the basic annotation which also works well. I discovered that trying to annotate to the plot after creating it was generally not working. For example

```
temp_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + 
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle("Title")
```

is working fine, but

```
temp_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + 
    geom_point() 
temp_plot + ggtitle("Title")
```

is not. The basic plot is drawn. But the title is not added....

Comment: Are you actually running the final line? If you are simply sourcing the entire script, this won't print the plot automatically. Wrap it in `print`. You should also make sure you are saving the modified plot, i.e., the final line should be: `temp_plot <- temp_plot + ggtitle("Title")`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've been wrapping it in plot to view it. And see it fine... but without the annotation. It makes sense to save the modified plot. So thanks. I'm doing that now. But get an error: Error in `ggplot_add()`:
! Can't add `plot(temp_plot)` to a <ggplot> object.

Comment: What are you passing as argument to `plot()` or `print()`?  (Use of `print()` is nowadays preferred).  `print( temp_plot + ggtitle("Title") )`
I cannot reproduce the problem. Have you loaded a package that redefines `plot()` or `+`?

Comment: I wasn't aware that print() is now preferred - I continue to learn! I've only really been using R for about 6 weeks, though several hours each day, as I analyse findings from a recently completed research project. Re-saving the plot combined with using print() does seem to have solved the problem. I still do not fully understand the cause as the packages I'm using for this sub-project (psych, dplyr, ggplot2 and moments) are widely used and will not be re-difining plot() or + . The plots are based on prcomp() from the stats package. Thanks for your helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help [re-saving the plot and using print(), not plot()] , I was able to create a function for creating several similar PCA plots with varying variables and numbers of variables (see below). Some of the code is idiosyncratic to this particular series of similar plots and I'm sure my code can be improved - but it works for my current needs! A list created with pcomp(), a string of text for the plot title, and a list of variable names are passed to the function:

```
PCA_plot <- function(temp_pca,title_text,temp_variable_names) {
  
  # Principal Component Analysis Individual Scores and loadings for plots
  temp_pca_scores <- as.data.frame(temp_pca[["x"]])
  temp_pca_loadings <- as.data.frame(temp_pca[["rotation"]])
  
  # Proportion of variance for Principle Components 1 and 2
  pov1 <- summary(temp_pca)[[6]][[2]]
  pov1 <- sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*pov1)
  pov2 <- summary(temp_pca)[[6]][[5]]
  pov2 <- sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*pov2)
  
  # Axes labels
  PC1_lab <- paste0("Principle Component 1 (", pov1," of variance)")
  PC2_lab <- paste0("Principle Component 2 (", pov2," of variance)")
  
  # Note 
  str_note <- "NOTE: For clarity,\nthe loadings are plotted\nat five times the scale\nof the individual points"
  
  temp_plot <- ggplot(temp_pca_scores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) + 
    geom_point() 
  
  temp_plot <-  temp_plot +  ggtitle(title_text) +
    xlab(PC1_lab) +
    ylab(PC2_lab)  +
    ylim(-5,5) +
    xlim(-5,5) +
    geom_point(position= "jitter", size= 1.2) +
    annotate("text",x=-4,y=4,label= str_note, size= 3) + 
    theme_light()
  
var_number <- length(temp_pca[["sdev"]])

for(i in 1:var_number) {
  
  if(i==1){
    keys <- paste0("1. ",temp_variable_names[1])
    }
  else {
    key <- paste0("\n",i,". ",temp_variable_names[i])
    keys <- paste0(keys,key)
    }
  
  temp_plot <- temp_plot +
    annotate(geom = "segment", x = 0, xend = temp_pca_loadings[i,1]*5, y = 0, yend = temp_pca_loadings[i,2]*5, 
             arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.2,"cm"),end = "last", type = "closed")) + 
    annotate(geom= "text", x=sum((temp_pca_loadings[i,1]*5),-0.2), y=sum(temp_pca_loadings[i,2]*5,0.1), label=i) 
}

temp_plot <- temp_plot +
  annotate(geom= "text", x=0.8, y=-3.7, label=keys, size=3, hjust=0) 
 
  return(temp_plot)
  
}
```